# Integral of tangential component along a Cliéle-curve

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm struggling to evaluate this integral.

$$\Phi(x,y,z)=7y^2+7e^{xz}+\ln(8(x^2+y^2+z^2))$$

$$\vec{F}(x,y,z)=\nabla\Phi(x,y,z)$$

I'm supposed to find the integral of the tangential component of $\vec{F}$ along the Clélie-curve described as:

\begin{align}
x&=5\sin(3\theta)\cos(\theta) \\[0.5ex]
y&=5\sin(3\theta)\sin(\theta) \\[0.5ex]
z&=5\cos(3\theta)
\end{align}

where $\theta$ goes form $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

I've managed to find the partial derivatives:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial x}&=\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+z^2}+7ze^{xz} \\[0.7ex]
\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial y}&=14y+\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \\[0.7ex]
\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial z}&=7xe^{xz}+\frac{2z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}
\end{align}

How do I evaluate the integral of the tangential component of $\vec{F}$  along the Clélie-curve?